# Issue with .dae image load in Scenekit

Tags: scenekit, ios11, arkit

I tried to import .dae images into the scene kit. The image gets imported into the scene kit. However after importing the image the texture, colour etc is not seen properly. I need to manually edit the transform value and also the texture parameters like diffuse, transparency etc to restore the original .dae image on the scene kit. Any inputs/suggestions to overcome this issue will be very helpful.

Comment: Hi @shri, did you ever manage to solve this? I'm facing the exact same problem

Comment: One observation is when the model is not unwrapped this issue is seen. We need to make sure the mapping coordinates is set to UV Map.